# Error in database class in data fetching query

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am developing a app in android and here i want to fetch data from table according to `rowId` and `subjectId` but I am getting this error,

```
The method query(boolean, String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments 
(boolean, String, String[], String, String, null, null, null, null)
```

And the here's that query,

```
public Cursor getText(long rowId, long subId) throws SQLException 
{
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
        KEY_id, KEY_ques,KEY_correctans,KEY_wrongans1,KEY_wrongans2,KEY_wrongans3,KEY_subject,KEY_subjectid }, KEY_id + "="
        + rowId, KEY_subjectid + "=" + subId,null,null, null,null);
if (mCursor != null) 
{
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;
}
```

I want to fetch table data as where `subId` = `KEY_subjectid` and `rowId` = `KEY_id`

If any thing is not clear in this question please ask me. And if its clear please help me..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to following:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
        KEY_id, KEY_ques,KEY_correctans,KEY_wrongans1,KEY_wrongans2,KEY_wrongans3,KEY_subject,KEY_subjectid }, KEY_id + "="
        + rowId + " AND " + KEY_subjectid + "=" + subId,null, null,null, null,null);
```

The 5-th parameter needs to be a String array, not a string the way you have. The 4-th parameter is the `WHERE` SQLite clause.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
public Cursor getText(long rowId, long subId) throws SQLException 
    {
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+DATABASE_TABLE+" where KEY_subjectid="+subId+" and KEY_id="+rowId+"",null);
    if (mCursor != null) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for telling this and thanks for shorten my query too :P :)